# Understanding a statement in the proof of Mercer's theorem

Tags: stochastic-processes, uniform-convergence

In the [wikipedia proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercer%27s_theorem) of Mercer's theorem, it says that 
$$\sum_{i=1}^\infty \lambda_i |e_i(t) e_i(s)| \leq \sup_{x \in [a,b]} |K(x,x)|,$$
implies that the sequence
$$ \sum_{i=1}^\infty \lambda_i e_i(t) e_i(s) $$

converges absolutely and uniformly on $[a, b] \times [a, b]$. How does the uniform convergence follow here?

Comment: Use the Weierstrass M test

Comment: @fGDu94 This won't do I think. My current understanding is that Dini's theorem must be employed.